# how to extract values from a list based on conditions in different data frames

Tags: dataframe, find

I have a table (Table1) with column of IDs and other values linked to each ID (rows). I need to create a new column in a second table "condition" according to the values found in the Table1 with exact same IDs. Table1 and Table2 have few common IDs and I need to identify which are already in Table1.

```
Example Table1:
ID       Condition
2345     old
2346     old
2347     new

Table 2:
ID     Condition based on table1 *\<- What I need to add!*
2345     old
2348     not-found
```

I am a beginner.
I need all instructions from attaching data frames, find the values and add the column with instructions. Thank YOU SO MUCH!

Just exploring different solutions. I know it is not complicated but don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using pd.merge ([good explainations here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html))
In this case, a left join will keep all the ids of table 2

```
df=pd.merge(Table2, Table1, on='ID', how='left')
```

Comment: Error in pd.merge(casos, data, on = "IDs", how = "left") : 
  could not find function "pd.merge".  
It seems I need to install pandas first! (need help with that too)

Comment: Is it possible to solve the problem ONLY with R scripts. No extra Python resources or extra libraries to install? (I have no clue how to do that).
Need help!!!